# Things to be taken care Before Running Stellar Horizon Test Cases

Tags: go, horizon, ginkgo, stellar

I have cloned the Stellar Horizon Repo from GitHub written in Go.
I thought to run the test cases first.where the test cases have been written by using GINKGO Testing Framework. I have been running the test cases using ginkgo command
eg : ginkgo (package path name will be given here). 
This is how I run test cases. Test cases for particular package has been executing properly. 
But I am getting a panic in the first test file only. Which I debugged and found that the panic is occurring while running a command. Please find the below details for reference .

File name : **action_accounts_test.go**
func name : TestAccountAction_Show() // Has been defined below

```
func TestAccountActions_Show(t *testing.T) {

    ht := StartHTTPTest(t, "allow_trust") **// This function is not returning anything. Its //getting panic inside this //** 
    defer ht.Finish()
    // existing account
    w := ht.Get(
        "/accounts/GCXKG6RN4ONIEPCMNFB732A436Z5PNDSRLGWK7GBLCMQLIFO4S7EYWVU",
    )

    if ht.Assert.Equal(200, w.Code) {
        var result horizon.Account
        err := json.Unmarshal(w.Body.Bytes(), &result)
        ht.Require.NoError(err)
        ht.Assert.Equal("8589934593", result.Sequence)

        ht.Assert.NotEqual(0, result.LastModifiedLedger)
        for _, balance := range result.Balances {
            if balance.Type == "native" {
                ht.Assert.Equal(uint32(0), balance.LastModifiedLedger)
            } else {
                ht.Assert.NotEqual(uint32(0), balance.LastModifiedLedger)
            }
        }
    }

    // missing account
    w = ht.Get("/accounts/GDBAPLDCAEJV6LSEDFEAUDAVFYSNFRUYZ4X75YYJJMMX5KFVUOHX46SQ")
    ht.Assert.Equal(404, w.Code)
}
```

I did a Debugging and found that its getting panic in the below func call which happens inside the above func **StartHTTPTest()**

```
scenarios.Load(StellarCoreDatabaseURL(), stellarCorePath)
scenarios.Load(DatabaseURL(), horizonPath)
```

Definition of the particular func

```
func Load(url string, path string) {

    log.Println("database url", url, "   Path : ", path)
    sql, err := Asset(path)
    log.Println("Print err:", err, "  sql :", sql)
    if err != nil {
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    reader := bytes.NewReader(sql)
    cmd := exec.Command("psql", url)
    cmd.Stdin = reader

    err = cmd.Run() **// Exactly here it return some error**
    log.Println("Print err", err)

    if err != nil { **// Since err is not nil .the statement will get executed .**
        **log.Panic(err)**
    }
}
```

The Error returned by **cmd.Run()** is  **exit status 2**
I just printed the error and found this is the error **exit status 2**

**What is the reason for the particular error?**

Comment: do you have psql installed on your system?

Comment: psql has been installed